# Como criar vetor de estrutura dentro de função

Tags: c, funções, estrutura-de-dados

Bom dia! Eu fiquei novamente de recuperação na matéria de algoritmos, o que mais me pegou foi estrutura e passagem de parâmetros. Resolvi criar uma atividade para treinar para recuperação de segunda-feira.

Seguindo os slides do professor eu finalmente fiz, o código está funcionando, o que não explica é... Como fazer rodar com for, eu tenho uma estrutura de dados e passo ela para uma função usando ponteiros.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

typedef struct mercearia
{
    char mercadoria[20];
    int quantidade;
    int valor;

} mercearia;


void EstruturaCadastro(struct mercearia *x)
{
    printf("\n");

    printf("Insira nome do produto: ");
    scanf("%s", &(*x).mercadoria);setbuf(NULL, stdin);

    printf("Insira a quantidade do produto: ");
    scanf("%i", &(*x).quantidade);setbuf(NULL, stdin);

    printf("Insira o valor do produto: R$ ");
    scanf("%i", &(*x).valor);setbuf(NULL, stdin);
}

void ExibirCadastroProdutos(struct mercearia x)
{
    printf("\n");

    printf("\nO produto cadastrado %s", x.mercadoria);
    printf("\nValor quantidade do produto %i", x.quantidade);
    printf("\nValor da unidade do produto %i", x.valor);

}

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        struct mercearia produto;

        EstruturaCadastro(&produto);
        ExibirCadastroProdutos(produto);
    }
```

Eu imaginei que funcionaria da seguinte forma:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

typedef struct mercearia
{
    char mercadoria[20];
    int quantidade;
    int valor;

} mercearia;


void EstruturaCadastro(struct mercearia *x)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Insira nome do produto: ");
        scanf("%s", &(*x)[i].mercadoria);setbuf(NULL, stdin);

        printf("Insira a quantidade do produto: ");
        scanf("%i", &(*x)[i].quantidade);setbuf(NULL, stdin);

        printf("Insira o valor do produto: R$ ");
        scanf("%i", &(*x)[i].valor);setbuf(NULL, stdin);
    }
}

void ExibirCadastroProdutos(struct mercearia x)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nO produto cadastrado %s", x.mercadoria);
        printf("\nValor quantidade do produto %i", x.quantidade);
        printf("\nValor da unidade do produto %i", x.valor);
    }
}

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        struct mercearia produto[5];

        EstruturaCadastro(&produto);
        ExibirCadastroProdutos(produto);
    }
```

Mas ai ele me retorna 300 mil erros... Alguém poderia apontar onde estou errando?

Erros apresentados pela IDE:

||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c||In function 'EstruturaCadastro':|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|22|error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|22|warning: passing argument 2 of 'setbuf' from incompatible pointer type|

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\stdio.h|193|note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|25|error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|25|warning: passing argument 2 of 'setbuf' from incompatible pointer type|

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\stdio.h|193|note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|28|error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|28|warning: passing argument 2 of 'setbuf' from incompatible pointer type|

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\stdio.h|193|note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c||In function 'main':|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|50|warning: passing argument 1 of 'EstruturaCadastro' from incompatible pointer type|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|14|note: expected 'struct mercearia *' but argument is of type 'struct mercearia (*)[5]'|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|51|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'ExibirCadastroProdutos'|

C:\Users\lelre\Documents\1 - Pessoal\Faculdade\ALG\Lista de atividades\Arquivo de testes.c|32|note: expected 'struct mercearia' but argument is of type 'struct mercearia *'|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Bom dia Lelre! Se possível, coloque por favor os erros apresentados juntamente com sua pergunta, para facilitar a análise do problema.

Comment: Bom dia chefe! Adicionei os erros apresentados pela IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando o trecho de código que usa um vetor de estruturas, tenho as seguintes observações.

```
typedef struct mercearia { ... } mercearia;
```

Depois dessa definição de tipo, `mercearia` pode ser usado como uma abreviação para o tipo `struct mercearia`, tornando o código muito mais limpo e claro. Assim

```
struct mercearia produto[5];
```

pode ser rescrito como

```
mercearia produto[5];
```

Outro ponto é o `scanf`. `scanf` exige que você passe o endereço do espaço de memória que você quer armazenar determinada informação. O operador `&` faz o acesso a tal endereço.

Portanto, sua função `EstruturaCadastro` precisa ser modificada.

```
void EstruturaCadastro(mercearia *x)
{
    scanf("%s", x[i].mercadoria); // para array de char não é necessário
    scanf(" %i", &(x[i].quantidade)); // espaço em branco consome \n do scanf anterior
    scanf(" %i", &(x[i].valor));
}
```

Sua função `ExibirCadastroProdutos` precisa receber um ponteiro para `mercearia` para poder percorrer o array que é passado como parâmetro

```
void ExibirCadastroProdutos(mercearia *x)
```

Há alguns outros ajustes menores que precisam ser feitos. Veja o código funcionando [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/SlightUniformPangolin).

Comment: Muito obrigado, o código está funcionando 100%!

Comment: @LelreFerreira considere marcar a resposta como aceita.